# Too many arguments error while using shell script on cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I am trying to run a script on cygwin prompt.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa $email
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
mkdir -p /proj/env
ln -s /usr/bin/proj/env/bin
```

and running it as email="john.warnet" sh script1.sh.

But it is showing error as

```
  Too many arguments.
   usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
              [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -l [-v] [-E fingerprint_hash] [-f input_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -D pkcs11
   ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
   ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
   ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
   ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
   ssh-keygen -G output_file [-v] [-b bits] [-M memory] [-S start_point]
   ssh-keygen -T output_file -f input_file [-v] [-a rounds] [-J num_lines]
              [-j start_line] [-K checkpt] [-W generator]
   ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-n principals]
              [-O option] [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
   ssh-keygen -L [-f input_keyfile]
   ssh-keygen -A
   ssh-keygen -k -f krl_file [-u] [-s ca_public] [-z version_number]
              file ...
   ssh-keygen -Q -f krl_file file ...
   Agent pid 1344
   Identity added: /home/HP/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/HP/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

I tried running the script by writing the command on prompt instead of copying.But couldnt find the solution.

Comment: _usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
              [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]_  **It says you cannot pass more than 1 arguments with -t** and the argument will be from these **[dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]** options only

Comment: So, what should i do then. Moreover when am trying to run the script as          sh script1.sh email="john.warnet@gmail.com", no error is being shown, but the variable email can not be passed to the script and $email is being replaced by blank.I cant figure out how to execute the script then.

Comment: you are accessing email in wrong way inside your **script1.sh** you need to access it using correct way. most simple is like run your script as                **sh script1.sh john.warnet@gmail.com** and access it inside script using $1

Comment: I tried out this and ran the script as sh script1.sh john.warret@gmail.com and replaced $email with $1, but still it is showing the same error as "too many arguments".

Comment: What i was trying to say was you can access this argument inside script.sh using $1 to do any other operation like echo or anything else. but you cannot pass with **ssh-keygen -t rsa $1** due to reason I mentioned in my first comment. why do you need to pass it with **ssh-keygen** ??

Comment: email is required to be passed as argument as ssh-keygen -t rsa $email , as it leads to generation of id_rsa.pub file with email passed as an argument added in end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can run it like below in case you need to pass email address as an argument to ssh-keygen

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa  -C $1
```